# consuming wcf service self hosted in a windows service through angular component

Tags: angular, wcf

I have e wcf self hosted in a windows service.
I consume it by a simple code in c# like that follow

```
public IHttpActionResult GetPS()
    {
        var status="";
        var myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        var myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8080/PSCservice");
        using (var myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IServiceInterface>(myBinding, myEndpoint))
        {
            IServiceInterface client = null;

            try
            {
                client = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
                status=client.GetPSCStatus(-1);
                ((ICommunicationObject)client).Close();
                myChannelFactory.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                (client as ICommunicationObject)?.Abort();
            }
            return Ok(status);

        }

    }
```

I'm new in angular and I'm trying to do the same but in angular.
Can someone give me the right way?

Thanks

Comment: follow wsdl detail

Comment: You can refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49558714/consume-same-wcf-service-from-angular-2-and-silverlight-application